# Page content is showed above the fixed header

Tags: html, asp.net-core, layout

I am using a fixed position header in my main layout page. But when I call an html page from an anchor tag  , it is showed always above the header.  How can I show the content inside 'Renderbody()'  from all the pages. Here is  the code in '_Layout.cshmtl'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyCompany</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

</head>    
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" id="home">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="fixed-top">
        </div>
        </header>
        <div class="body-container">
                 @RenderBody()
            </div>
   </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
```

My default page is 'Index.cshmtl' has shown below .This  index page is showed from 'Renderbody' section. But when I call another page 'projectdetails from Index page , it is showed  above  the header part of the layout. The content of the projectdetails  should be showed after header part ,inside Renderbody() section. If I remove 'fixed-top' , from layout , it will show correctly. How can I show the views inside the render body section when I use fixed-top.

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Projectdetails" asp-route-itemId= 1 class="card-link ">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I remove 'fixed-top' , from layout , it will show correctly. How
> can I show the views inside the render body section when I use
> fixed-top.

Position an element at the top of the viewport, from edge to edge. Be sure you understand the ramifications of fixed position in your project; Note that the fixed top header will overlay your other content.

To fix this, you may need to add aditional CSS, add a margin-top (to the content) that is equal or larger than the height of your fixed top header.

Try to add below code in your _Layout.cshtml.

```
           <style>
                .body-container {
                    /*  */
                    /* top: 0;*/
                    bottom: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    margin-top: 200px;
                }
            </style>
```

A similar Demo to achieve your need:

_Layout.cshtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - MyCompany</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.carousel.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/owl.theme.default.min.css" />

</head>
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#main-nav" id="home">
    <header id="header">
   
        <div class="fixed-top">

            <a class="navbar-brand" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">MyCompany</a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex justify-content-between">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Privacy">Privacy</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <style>
                .body-container {
                    /*  */
                    /* top: 0;*/
                    bottom: 0;
                    right: 0;
                    left: 0;
                    margin-top: 200px;
                }
            </style>

    </header>

    <div class="body-container">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Index.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


    w  index


<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Projectdetails" asp-route-itemId=1 class="card-link ">Read More</a>
</div>
```

Results:

1.Index:

[image]

2.Click Read more:

[image]